# getHost() or $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] from command component in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I am executing a task (command component) in Symfony2 and I would like to use

```
$this->getRequest()->getHost()
```

just like I do in a controller. What is the way to get that value (/Command/MyCommand.php)?

I know I can do `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`.  But, I would like to use Symfony for this.

Comment: You can't access $_SERVER in CLI btw :) Your command component has no request, that's probably why you can't get it. Why don't you use a symfony parameter ?

Comment: I like your `i would like to use symfony for this` approach ;)

Comment: @Gmajoulet of course you can. But do not expect HTTP request related fields in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case if you'd need host, you could get it from router context:

```
$host = $this->getContainer()->get('router')->getContext()->getHost();
```

But since you are looking for `SERVER_NAME` - it will not be available during script executing from console.

Workaround for this situation could be to define your parameter in parameters and get it `Command`:

```
$serverName = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('your_defined_param');
```

Comment: this is giving me "localhost" value :/

Comment: @TroodoN-Mike ah... Misread your question... Then the only workaround is to define it in parameters and get via container. Updated my answer

Comment: why would i want to get parameter? I am interested in host and $_SERVER variable

Comment: @TroodoN-Mike You are executing your command directly from bash - script in this case is not aware of your host configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old question, but it's ranking high in the Google results.

Since Symfony 2.1 you can add additional fields to parameters.yml

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    router.request_context.host: example.org
    router.request_context.scheme: https
    router.request_context.base_url: my/path
```

This is applicable to all versions up to Symfony 4.1

It's worth mentioning that you'll also have to use **url** (absolute) rather than **path** (relative)

Link to the manual [Symfony.com - How to Generate URLs from the Console](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/console/request_context.html)

Comment: Just to clarify, @Vitalii Zurian's solution is correct, but using these particular parameters means you can access the variables from TWIG if required.